# rust regex numbers as words and numerics

Tags: regex, rust, numbers

i'm trying to write regex expresions in rust using regex library and i want to find all numbers in string, they can be represented as word (one) or numeric (1), it can only be one digit number, so my problem is in strings like "eightwo" there is kinda two numbers (eight, two) but what i wrote only finds number eight.

so my question is can this pattern be written or what should i write instead of pattern matching to solve this kind of a problem?

my expression:

```
let re = Regex::new(r"[0-9]|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|ten").unwrap();
```

Comment: You could anchor this at the start/end, like `^[0-9]+$` which means "one or more digits", giving you more control over what is permitted. You'll need to eliminate "9ten" but allow "ninetytwo" and perhaps "ninety-two".

Comment: @tadman can you write full expression? and pattern should match all of possibilitities like 91 -> 9,1; 9two -> 9, two; twone -> two, one

Comment: I can steer you in the right direction. I'm not here to solve every problem single-handedly, you know. [Regex101](https://regex101.com) is a good place to prototype this.

Comment: Advent of Code hint: do you really need *all* numbers, or just the first and the last?

Comment: If the _match_ is a numeral, could you just presume the rest of the word is just another numeral?  For example, `(?:one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|ten).*?\b`.

Answer (score 0):

One possible idea is to use [`find_at()`](https://docs.rs/regex/latest/regex/struct.Regex.html#method.find_at), but instead of giving it the end of the previous match, give it its start + 1. This way, it will never match the same one again, but it can match overlapping matches.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is for Advent of Code.
The way I solved it is with the following code:

```
for val in MATCHES.iter() {
    let first_result = line.find(val);
    let last_result  = line.rfind(val);
    if first_result == None {
        continue;
    }
    if ! found {
        first_index = first_result;
        first_value = val;
        last_index  = last_result;
        last_value  = val;
        found = true;
    } else {
        if first_result < first_index {
            first_index = first_result;
            first_value = val;
        }
        if last_result > last_index {
            last_index = last_result;
            last_value = val;
        }
    }
}
```

and MATCHES is defined as follows:

```
const MATCHES: [&str; 18] = [
    "1", "one",
    "2", "two",
    "3", "three",
    "4", "four",
    "5", "five",
    "6", "six",
    "7", "seven",
    "8", "eight",
    "9", "nine"
];
```